# Trying to sort text into groups to decrypt alphanumeric codes (Python IDE 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m using Python IDE 3. My goal is this:
If I have a string of text, ‘ABCDEFGHIJKL’, I want to sort it into groups, like three groups (‘ADGJ’,’BEHK’,’CFIL’).
I require input for this, but the prompts aren’t showing up and I can’t type in input. Here’s my code:

```
#data
code_text = input('Text: ').lower()
code_skip = int(input('Shift length: '))
code_list = []
#function
def countSkip(text, shift, list):
    i = 0
    set = 1
    def iterate():
      if set <= shift:
        for e in text:
#make sure the set starts at the right place
          if e.index()+1 < set:
            pass
          elif shift != 0:
            if i = shift:
              list.append(e)
              i = 0
            i += 1
          else:
            list.append(e)
          set += 1
    iterate()
#calling function    
countSkip(code_text, code_shift, code_list)
```

Comment: CodeReview@SE [improves working code you present from your project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - `can’t type in input` means *not ready for review* (here).

Comment: In the future, please use the `python` tag along with the version used (`python-2.x` or `python-3.x`), as some users watch the `python` tag, but not specifically the version.